# How do you access a column name in a polars expression?

Tags: python-polars

I implemented a sigmoid transformation in polars as follows:

```py
def sigmoid(c:pl.Expr)->pl.Expr:
    return 1 / ((-c).exp() + 1)
```

This works great, except that by polars naming conventions the resulting column is called `'literal'`

I could keep the column name by re-writing sigmoid as

```py
def sigmoid(c:pl.Expr)->pl.Expr:
    return ((c * -1).exp() + 1)**-1
```

But:
A. That is horrible
B. I don't want my code to have this "magical/invisible" tracking of column names

What I'd like to do is add a `.alias()` at the end of my function to ensure the column name is preserved.

The following pseudo-code expresses the idea:

```py
def sigmoid(c:pl.Expr)->pl.Expr:
    return (1 / ((-c).exp() + 1)).alias(c.name)
```

However, polars expressions do not have a .name attribute.

How else could I keep the column name?

Not that I could do:

```py
df.select(
   pl.col('a').pipe(sigmoid).alias('a'), 
   pl.col('b').pipe(sigmoid).alias('b'), 
   pl.col('c').pipe(sigmoid).alias('c'), 
   ...
)
```

But that is cumbersome, and would not work well with

```py
df.select(
   pl.all().pipe(sigmoid)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods such as `.output_name` from the [meta namespace.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/meta.html#meta)

```
pl.col("a").meta.output_name()

# 'a'
```

```
pl.when(pl.col("a") == 1).then(pl.col("b")).otherwise(pl.col("c")).meta.output_name()

# 'b'
```

```
pl.when(pl.col("a") == 1).then(pl.col("b")).otherwise(pl.col("c")).meta.root_names()

# ['b', 'c', 'a']
```

```
def sigmoid(c:pl.Expr)->pl.Expr:
   return (1 / ((-c).exp() + 1)).alias(c.meta.output_name())

pl.DataFrame(dict(a = [1, 2, 3])).select(sigmoid(pl.col("a")))
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌──────────┐
│ a        │
│ ---      │
│ f64      │
╞══════════╡
│ 0.731059 │
│ 0.880797 │
│ 0.952574 │
└──────────┘
```